# laravel comment reply store not working

Tags: laravel, comments

i am creating a comment system with reply, but i have problem with reply store.
it does not working and display any error!
i do not know what to do!?
**i have polymorphic relation**

***comment controller***

```
 public function store(Request $request,Post $post)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'website' => 'nullable|active_url',
        'comment' => 'required|min:5'
    ]);

    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $comment->name = Auth::user()->fname;
    $comment->email = Auth::user()->email;
    $comment->website = $request->website;
    $comment->body = $request->comment;

    $post->comments()->save($comment);
    Session::flash('success', 'Comment Send Successfully');

    return back();
}

public function reply(Request $request,Comment $comment)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'website' => 'nullable|active_url',
        'commentReply' => 'required|min:5'
    ]);

    $reply = new Comment();
    $reply->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $reply->name = Auth::user()->fname;
    $reply->email = Auth::user()->email;
    $reply->website = $request->website;
    $reply->body = $request->replyComment;

    $comment->comments()->save($reply);
    Session::flash('success', 'Comment Replyed Successfully');

    return back();
}
```

***comment model***

```
 protected $fillable = [
    'parent_id', 'user_id', 'post_id', 'name', 'email', 'website', 'body', 'approved'
];

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}

public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Comment::class,'commentable');
}
```

***and these are my routes***

```
/* comment */
Route::post('/post/{post}/comment','CommentController@store')->name('comment.store');
Route::post('/comment/reply/{comment}','CommentController@reply')->name('comment.reply');
```

i do not have problem with comment storing, problem is reply does not store.
this is problem! :)

Comment: where do you store the replay ?

Comment: i think your validation failed, try to dd($this->validate($request,[
        'website' => 'nullable|active_url',
        'commentReply' => 'required|min:5'
    ]);); in reply method

Comment: you have `replyComment` in your request and you have added `commentReply` in validation. so the validation will be always false

Comment: you mean like this: dd($this->validate($request,[
            'website' => 'nullable|active_url',
            'commentReply' => 'required|min:5'
        ]));

but it does not working

Comment: change `commentReply` in validation to `replyComment`